# How to test for collection ID in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

Several of my methods take in IDs as input. I was wondering how could I use the check package to check if these were valid ids or not. It seems Meteor doesn't use the conventions defined in the Mongo docs.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mongo.Collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) documentation we see that upon creating it takes an option `idGeneration` which is used to determine the method of generating the _id fields of new documents. The default method is a random string, meaning that you should use `check(docId, String)`.

The other method is using random [Mongo.ObjectID](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_object_id) values. For this method you can use `Match.Where(<function>)` to determine that the id is valid with a simple regex.

Comment: But then any string gets through for the random string idGeneration method. Is there a better way